# Water does not flow out of some hot tub jets but does produce air when the air pump is turned on

Tags: pool, hot-tub

I have an inground pool/hot tub combo. The water does partially drain from the hot tub when the pool pump is off which I'm sure is the root cause of the problem. We will be making that repair but I want to find out how to get water flowing through those Jets again once we make that repair I hope you can help.

Comment: Would you care to [edit] your post to clarify what, exactly, the problem is? You indicate what you think the "root cause of the problem" is, but don't ever specify the problem itself.

Comment: Water doesn't come thru some of the jets. I believe they are blocked by air. This is an In ground hot tub that runs off the pool pump. Air goes through all of the jets even the blower is turned on but water does not go through 4 of the 6 jets

Answer (score 0):

My hot tub has 2 water pumps and 1 air pump.
When I turn on the air blower air is plumbed to both systems so air comes out of the upper (not in use water jets) the lower ones don’t get enough air pressure to push the water out. I have thought about adding a valve to provide the ability to shut off the air on the side not being used because the air bubbles are “cold” .

This is the reason on my tub that there are air bubbles coming out of the water jets not in use when the air pump is on.